# How to popup Modal Popup extender from Image button?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm working on an image viewer. If user clicks an image then it'd be displayed in a Modal. But its giving me an error that targetcontrolID is invalid.

Any Idea how to do this?

Code is below

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgItem" runat="server" imgURL="Image1.jpg" />

  <asp:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
  targetcontrolid="imgItem" popupcontrolid="Panel1">
  </asp:modalpopupextender>



 <asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
 <p>Image will be displayed here</p>
 </asp:panel>
</form>
```

Comment: We are going to need to see some code.

Comment: You can see the code now.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and its working fine, means it is showing me modal popup on image click. Only problem I can see is Invalid tag in Imagebutton that is imgURL. Kindly correct the imagebutton tag and retest:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgItem" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Thumbs/image1.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

please replace imgURL with ImageUrl. Add the image control inside panel also. and add some css.

Comment: did it, but nothing popped up.

Comment: Try this code <asp:ImageButton ID="imgItem" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Thumbs/image1.png" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="imgItem" CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Thumbs/image1.png" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>

Comment: and this css -  <style type="text/css">
        .modalBackground
        {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .modalPopup
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 140px;
        }
    </style>

Comment: Still the same error, targetcontrolID="imgItem" is invalid.

Comment: This page is child page, part of a master page. May be this error is occurring due to this reason.

Comment: it wont affect . all the controls should be in same page i.e modalpopupextender , panel and your targetcontrol

Comment: Every thing is on same page. Let me do lil bit more R&D and see if i find some answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick event of image button and in code behind onclick event you can call the modalpopup like modalpopup1.show();